# how to create CSV string from DataTable in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, csv, datatable

I'm fetching data from database as a `DataTable` and need to convert into CSV string in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a generic method with DataTable, CSV Headers, DataTable Columns parameters:

```
    Private Function CSVBuilder(dt As DataTable, headers As List(Of String), columns As List(Of String)) As String
        Dim sCSV = New StringBuilder(String.Join(",", headers))
        sCSV.Append(Environment.NewLine)

        Dim view As New DataView(dt)
        Dim tDt As DataTable = view.ToTable(True, columns.ToArray)

        For Each row As DataRow In tDt.Rows
            '-- Handle comma
            sCSV.Append(String.Join(",", (From rw In row.ItemArray Select If(rw.ToString.Trim.Contains(","), String.Format("""{0}""", rw.ToString.Trim), rw.ToString.Trim))))
            sCSV.Append(Environment.NewLine)
        Next

        Return sCSV.ToString
    End Function
```

And then call in your code to get CSV string:

```
CSVBuilder(dataTable,
           New List(Of String) From {"Header Column 1", "Header Column 2", ...},
           New List(Of String) From {"DataTableColumn1", "DataTableColumn2", ...})
```

Comment: Seems like an odd API surface. I'd think you would write the method to either assume the datatable _already_ has the correct columns, or ask for the DataView directly instead. Additionally, I'd infer the headers from the `.Columns` collection in the datatable. Then you only need one parameter to the method: `CSVBuilder(dt)`. Finally, I might also prefer to return a stream, or ask for a stream to write into.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, thank you for the response. Yes, I can pass datatable columns in the `.Columns` collection but for CSV file headers I think, still need to pass headers list to CSVBuilder method. Do you have any better idea to manage headers as well in the datatable and pass that datatable only to the CSVBuilder method?

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comment, since this wouldn't fit in that space:

```
Private Function CSVBuilder(dt As DataTable) As String
    Dim sCSV As New StringBuilder()

    'Headers
    Dim delimeter As String = ""
    For Each col As String In dt.Columns.Select(Func(col) col.ColumnName)
         If col.Contains(",") Then col = """" & col & """"
          sCSV.Append(delimeter).Append(col)
          delimeter = ","
    Next
    sCSV.AppendLine()

    For Each row As DataRow In tDt.Rows
        sCSV.AppendLine(String.Join(",", (From rw In row.ItemArray Select If(rw.ToString.Trim.Contains(","), String.Format("""{0}""", rw.ToString.Trim), rw.ToString.Trim))))
    Next

    Return sCSV.ToString
End Function
```

Now, I did remove this code:

```
Dim view As New DataView(dt)
Dim tDt As DataTable = view.ToTable(True, columns.ToArray)
```

But I wouldn't do this as part of the `CSVBuilder()` method. If you want to project a specific view of a table, I would do that separately from creating the CSV data. You could make a separate method for it:

```
Public Function GetProjection(dt As DataTable, columns As IEnumerable(Of String)) As DataTable
    Dim view As New DataView(dt)
    Return view.ToTable(True, columns.ToArray())
End Function
```

And then you call them together like this:

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = '.... original table here
 Dim columns() As String = '... the columns you want

 Dim csv As String = CSVBuilder(GetProjection(dt, columns))
```

or like this:

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = '.... original table here
 Dim columns() As String = '... the columns you want

 Dim dt1 = GetProjection(dt, columns)
 Dim csv As String = CSVBuilder(dt1)
```

This is called [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), and it's a good thing to do.

Finally, I'll repeat my suggestion to think in terms of writing to a stream. Long strings with repeated append operations can cause real problems for the .Net garbage collector. Using `StringBuilder` can help, but won't fully eliminate these problems. Writing to a Stream, which is often connected to a file on disk, gives you the opportunity to completely eliminate this issue. Plus, it will likely save you work later on.

Comment: I will do more experiment on this. So I'm working on CSV sending in the email attachment. If you have any good example of code that I can refer and send CSV file in the email using Stream that would help a lot.